# Extract rows using a delimiter and append as column in a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, grep, split

I have a file that contains data something like:

```
a 1
b 2
c,d,e 3,4,5
f 6
g,h 7,8
```

... and I need the output like:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
f 6
g 7
h 8
```

I can do this using python, but I want to try this using shell scripting. I was thinking of first isolating the rows that contain the delimiter ',' and then work ahead. I have used this so far to isolate the the rows:

```
perl -F, -ane 'print if $#F >=1' filename
```

... but I am stuck in the next step.

Comment: Why don't you do it with Python?

Comment: Why do you say you want to try shell scripting and then post a perl program?

Comment: I want to try shell scripting....however, the perl solution was the one available at that time. Also, I have done it with python, but want to get into shell scripting.

Comment: You have so many working answers. Why don't you accept the one that helped you to most to close this question?

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -lane '@v=split/,/,$F[1]; $i=0;
              print "$_ $v[$i++]" for split/,/,$F[0]' ip.txt
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
f 6
g 7
h 8
```

Split either the first/second column, initialize index counter and then print the pairs by iterating over splitting the other column

`-a` option will auto-split the input line on whitespaces and have the results in `@F` array

Comment: this will take more time because of splitting in a loop? isn't it?

Comment: splitting is done once.. loop happens on the result of split, which is an array with one or more elements.. if the solution is slow, you'll have to benchmark and improve as needed..

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** solution (assuming that number of "keys" (contained in the 1st field `$1`) would always correspond to number of "values" (contained in the 2nd field `$2`)):

```
awk '$1 ~ /,/{
         len = split($1, keys, ",");
         split($2, vals, ",");
         for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) print keys[i], vals[i];
         next
    }1' file
```

The output:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
f 6
g 7
h 8
```

Comment: or just `awk '{split($1,keys,","); split($2,vals,","); for (x in keys) print keys[x], vals[x]}' infile`

Comment: @αғsнιη, that is not optimal approach, cause it tries to call `split` twice even in cases when it's not needed

Comment: Yes the keys correspond to the values. This looks great. thank you

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it using the sed editor is:

```
sed -e '
   s/,/\n/
   s/\(\n.*[[:blank:]]\)\([^,]*\),/ \2\1/
   P;D
' input.file
```

**Working:**

- Clip the leading comma-separated element from the 2nd field.
- Then append this element in the 1st field's leading comma-separated element.
- Print the leading element of the 1st field and delete it after this.
- Repeat this procedure with what remains in the pattern space till it is empty.

Another method using Perl is:

```
perl -lane '
   my($kref, $vref, %h) = map { [split /,/] } @F[0,1];
   @h{@$kref} = @$vref;
   print "$_  $h{$_}" for @$kref;
' input.file
```

Another way is shown here:

```
perl -lpe 'print "$1 $3" while s/^([^,]*),(.*\h)([^,]*),/$2/' input.file
```

**Working:**

- Look at the regex this way: (Perl reads in a line at a time from the file) then:

  - **^([^,]*)** shall pick the first-field's leading comma-separated element of the current line. This is stored in $1 variable.
  - **(.*\h)** shall preserve, for the next iteration of the while loop, the intermediate contents beginning from the second comma-separated element of the first field to the beginning of the second comma-separated element of the second field. This is stored in the $2 variable.
  - **([^,]*)** shall pick the leading comma-separated element from the second field of the current line.This gets stored in the $3 variable.
  - Now "$1 $3" is printed out to STDOUT and the line is shrunk to $2. The while loop now performs the operation all over again on this edited line, which is $2 of the previous line,..... this repeats till the s/// succeeds. The failure comes when we run out of commas. At which point , what remains in the line, "c 5" is printed to STDOUT by the default behavior of perl in the -p mode.
- Pluck out the leading comma-separated elements from the first and second fields.
- Print those elements and also shrink the current record by removing.
- Loop over  the current record while it's having 2 commas.
- Last pair is auto-printed due to the -p option of Perl.

---

```
perl -lane '
   my($kref, $vref) = map { [split /,/] } @F;
   print shift @$kref, " ", shift @$vref while @$kref && @$vref;
' input.file
```

**Working:**

- keys are stored in an array @$kref, corresponding values in @$vref. Note no hashes involved here.
- print the top of the arrays simultaneously and then remove the top ...rinse,repeat while both the arrays are non-empty.

**Output:**

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
f 6
g 7
h 8
```

Comment: I do not understand the `perl -lpe 'print "$1 $3" while s/^([^,]*),(.*\h)([^,]*),/$2/' input.file` . So this loop will take into account one par at a time?

Comment: @Anurag pls. see the explanation in the reply above.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk '{gsub(","," "); for(i=0;i<NF/2;i++) print $(i+1),$(i+1+NF/2)}' file
```

After removing the comma from each line, the script loops through half of the parameters of each line to print the first fields together with the field from the second half of the line.

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, the gsub replaces the comma with a whitespace and now every delimiter is a space. And then the loop does its work. Nice...Thank you

Answer (score 1):

"using shell scripting" -- this is bash:

```
while read -r key value; do
    IFS=, read -ra keys <<<"$key"
    IFS=, read -ra vals <<<"$value"
    for ((i=0; i < ${#keys[@]}; i++)); do
        echo "${keys[i]} ${vals[i]}"
    done
done <<END
a 1
b 2
c,d,e 3,4,5
f 6
g,h 7,8 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

With gnu sed

```
sed -E ':A;s/([^,]*),([^ ]*) ([^,]*),(.*)/\1 \3\n\2 \4/;tA' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the obfuscation...

```
perl -pe '1 while s/(.*),(.*\h)(.*),/$1 $3\n$2/' infile
```

Each substitution extracts last pair:

```
a,b,c 1,2,3  →  a,b 1,2  →  a 1
                c 3         b 2
                            c 3
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of solutions here *programmed* in perl, awk, sed, bash, ... but no script-solution.

```
# /bin/bash
f="yourFile"
paste -d' ' <(cut -d' ' -f1 "$f" | tr , '\n') <(cut -d' ' -f2 "$f" | tr , '\n')
```

or written differently

```
# /bin/bash
f() { cut -d' ' -f"$1" yourFile | tr , '\n'; }
paste -d' ' <(f 1) <(f 2)
```